# Android 12+ splash screen background color is ignored in dark mode

Tags: android, android-12

I am adding an Android 12+ splash screen to an existing app. I want to keep the existing splash screen for Android < 12, so I am defining the "new" splash screen styles in a "values-v31" folder. This is the content of `res/values-v31/styles.xml`:

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Splash Screen Theme (Android 12+)
         Ref: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate
     -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Splash">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_foreground</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This works fine when tested in the emulator (with a Pixel4a device). However when testing in a real device (Poco X4 Pro 5G) I found the background color is ignored when the device is configured in night mode. Duplicating the styles.xml file in a "values-night-v31" folder does not help.

Am I missing something?

**Edit:** The original question stated incorrectly that duplicating the styles.xml file in a "values-night-v31" folder fixed the problem. This is not correct.

Comment: Which *androidx.core:core-splashscreen* version do you use?

Comment: None. I am not using the compat library, since I only want to use the new splash screen for Android 12+.

Comment: Does your `@color/primary` has its night theme variant?

Comment: You will need two theme files: one for the day and the other for the night. Make sure you include the styles in both themes to get it working. Also, two color files: one for day and the other for the night, change colors there as per day and night mode.

Comment: No, that doesn't fix the issue either.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is related to `MIUI ROM`. Most of the `XIAOMI` devices that are using this branch of `Android` have `Dark Mode` issues(You can find a lot of reports about it by searching in Google). The `MIUI` tries to force `dark mode` on apps that don't support `dark theme` but it is not smart enough to handle it properly. So you need to `explicitly` tell the OS how to handle the dark mode in your app by defining your styles and themes in `values-night` folder and it is necessary to avoid this issue. Another way is the user exclude the app from applying dark mode using phone settings in this path `Settings->Display->More Dark Mode Options`. Of course, sometimes it does not work.

Comment: This makes sense, do you have any references describing this behaviour ?

Comment: Please check [here](https://geektech.me/miui-12-5-broke-dark-mode-in-popular-apps-xiaomi-wont-be-able-to-fix-the-problem/) and [here](https://piunikaweb.com/2021/08/05/miui-12-5-users-complain-of-dark-mode-issues-with-apps-like-messenger-snapchat/)

Comment: I am awarding the bounty to this answer as it indeed looks like a MIUI bug, even though I still don’t know exactly what is going on or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your old splash screen you like to keep on older android versions uses a windowBackground drawable?

Here is how i managed to do this.

I've implemented the androidx.core:core-splashscreen and setup my theme as following:

`values/themes.xml` contains the following style where i use my old windowBackground:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

And in `values-v31/themes.xml` i've configured this style for android 12+ using the new native splashscreen.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```